# Are we allowed to ask something from a book in SO?

Tags: discussion

Hello I'm learning by myself with books and sometimes I find myself confused and feeling lost about some of terms on that book. Are we allowed to ask such question in Stackoverflow and help me to understand some of paragraph? especially if I can't find it by Googling and it's not about code but it's about understanding that I can't grasp it because lack of my experience BUT YES the book is about programming.

Comment: Yes, I think you can write up a valid question, as long you rephrase those paragraphs clearly, and explicitly explain what you didn't understood there.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, I'm a bit paranoid with downvote..hehehe. Yes, I will try my best to provide the Information as clear as possible :)

Comment: Sure you can, just provide a bit of context if you're able to -- that's more than most people here will ask for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can, so long as you formulate the question well.

For instance, a title of

> What does the passage in this book mean?

[is a terrible question title](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20what%20does%20this%20book%20mean).

Your title should be what you'd search for with this issue.  No one would search for "What does this passage mean?".  They may search for, "What does composition over inheritance mean?"

So that's the first step: Make sure your title reflects the problem you have (the actual words you don't understand), and not the topic (the fact that you don't understand what specific words mean).

The second step is to organize and format the question well.  Even with a terrible title, [this similar question organizes the question well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270320/what-exactly-does-this-statement-from-design-patterns-gof-book-mean).

Upvotes and the question staying open depend upon not just what you ask, but how you ask it.  The more care and attention you place in the formulation of your question, the more likely it'll be accepted by the community.

Comment: Thank you.. yeah I know and u re right. I just need to make sure this such question are not "out of topic" or something like that.

Comment: for questions like "What does the passage in this book mean?" I find this Prog.SE meta reference useful: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)**

Answer (score 2):

Yes,you can.

Since what you are asking is about helping you understand some things which are related to programming in a book, your question is on-topic for SO. Just make sure that you explain what is it that you find difficulty to understand. Also,the question must be clear and should not be too broad,i.e, don't ask several questions in one post. Feel free to post your question after taking care of the above things.

Comment: Thanks for the advices ;)